# Java API десериализация JSON: как узнать какое поле Объекта пришло?

Tags: java, rest, test-automation, jackson

Пишу АПИ тест, описал класс ошибок

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

в респонсе приходит только одно поле в зависимости от моделируемой ситуации. Соответственно при ассерте нужно понимать какое поле вытягивать. Если писать под каждую ситуацию тест это долго т.к. поля будут пополнятся. я данные на вход я подаю из файла. Например подаю ему на вход логин, неправильный пароль, и мессаг который должен быть в такой ситуации.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message": {
            "email": "Значение «Электронная почта» не является правильным email адресом."
        }
    }
}
```

И сравниваю

```
assertTrue(actualAnswer.getError().getMessage().getEmail().equals(errMessage));
```

но при следующей комбинации данных уже прийдет емейл и пример меседжа на неправильный емейл соответственно и асерт нужен другой.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message": {
            "password": "Пароль слишком слабый или содержит недопустимые символы! Разрешено использовать цифры верхний и нижний регистр букв латинского алфавита."
        }
    }
}
```

Пробовал **if** но все-равно **java.lang.NullPointerException** т.к. ищет имейл.
Подскажите как написать универсальный ассерт.

Comment: Вы не думали поменять структуру json. message{key: email/password, value:textAboutEmail/textAboutPassword}. С непредсказуемыми ключами работать сложновато.

Comment: @Maxim Что Вы имеете ввиду, по другому десереализовать ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри, для каждого кейса тебе надо добавить ожидаемое сообщение об ошибке.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String expectedErr;
}
```

А после делать идентичную проверку:

```
String actualErr = actualAnswer.getError().getMessage().getEmail();
assertEquals(acutalErr, expectedErr);
```

Теперь дело за малым, а именно наполнять файл кейсами.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете добавить в свой проект groovy класс со следующем методом

```
@SuppressWarnings("GrUnresolvedAccess")
static Map getChildMessage() {
    def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(sGetJson())
    return object.error.message as Map
}
```

где sGetJson() - функция возвращающая ваш json (String) 
Для добавления groovy класса, если у вас maven проект, добавьте  в pom.xml в dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

Соответственно получить тип сообщения с ошибкой можно так:

```
getChildMessage().keySet()[0]
```

а получить текст сообщения ошибки можно так:

```
getChildMessage().values().getAt(0)
```

Надеюсь вам это поможет.

Comment: Симкин Влад, решил добавить в файл с данными поле которое будет показывать какой  респонс ждать и делать ассерты по оператору `case`

Comment: ```switch (validation){
            case "email":
                assertTrue(actualAnswer.getError().getMessage().getEmail().equals(errMessage));
                break;
            case "password":
                assertTrue(actualAnswer.getError().getMessage().getPassword().equals(errMessage));
                break;
            case "passwordConfirm":
                assertTrue(actualAnswer.getError().getMessage().getPasswordConfirm().equals(errMessage));
                break;
        }```